# Download, unzip and render web content in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a zip file hosted on a server, containing some web content (HTML, CSS, javascript and media files).

In a web app, is it somehow possible to download this file, unzip it and display the content, using javascript ?

In a native mobile app I would unzip the file on the file system and display the content in a webview using the "file://" protocol, but I think a web app can't do that, right ?

Comment: does the zip file have a single HTML file? that can be done - googled "browser unzip zip file"

Comment: @Bravo it has html, css and js files

Comment: yeah, that won't be easy then since the JS/CSS will be included using `<script>` or `<link>` tags, so ... where do you put these files!! I mean, there is a way, you process the HTML and inject the JS/CSS inline where it needs to go ... but then, what if the JS "imports" or the CSS "includes" other resources that are within the zip - then you'll be hard pressed getting it done .... so, it really depends on the complexity of the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible using a service worker, along with [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), as done in this project: https://github.com/gkjohnson/client-side-zip-server